# Howto Execute a action from domain class after the controller action is done in Grails

Tags: grails

Need to Execute a action from domain class after the controller action is done in Grails.

some thing like beforeInterceptor / afterInterceptor. But in generic i am looking for and need  to be automatically invoke this post save action from domain class.

Any kind of solution is appreciable.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this : http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping

Comment: Thanks Lalit.. It is similar kind of requirement for me. as I am very much new to Grails can u confirm me these events can be placed in Domain class?? or not.

Comment: Yes, It will work in domain class. There are lot of samples in the link itself. Also I have added this as an answer, please accept it if you think this is correct. It will be helpful for others who want something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at the link here: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping

You could use these events directly in domain class just be aware of not doing flush:true.

```
Do not attempt to flush the session within an event (such as with obj.save(flush:true)). Since events are fired during flushing this will cause a StackOverflowError.
```

Sample from the link.

```
class Person {
 private static final Date NULL_DATE = new Date(0)

 String firstName String lastName Date signupDate = NULL_DATE

 def beforeInsert() 
 { 
    if (signupDate == NULL_DATE) 
    { 
       signupDate = new Date() 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Hi Lalit,One more question how this beforeInsert() is invoked?? and when?

Comment: @Odaiah beforeInsert will be invoked just before the record is inserted in db. There is an event called afterInsert as well which will be invoked after the record is inserted.